# Flask Dance OAuth via Microsoft Azure errors

Tags: azure, flask, oauth-2.0, azure-web-app-service

I am testing an Azure web app that will use Flask Dance to authorize users via their Microsoft accounts. I took the code right from Azure's documentation:

```
blueprint = make_azure_blueprint(
    client_id="id_here",
    client_secret="secret_here")

app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix="/login")

@app.route('/')
def login():
    if not azure.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for("azure.login"))
        response = azure.get("/v1.0/me")
    assert resp.ok
    return "You are {mail} on Azure AD".format(mail=resp.json()["userPrincipalName"])
```

So when I run it, I get the login screen and then login, but then I get this error:

```
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

AADSTS50011: No reply address is registered for the application.
```

Based on the error, I believe I need to set up my local host somewhere, but I don't see a place to enter it. Also, if I just go to a different part of the page and bypass the login, it works even if I'm not logged in.

When I deploy it, I get a 502 error and am unable to connect to it (it was working before I set up the Azure blueprint part).

What am I missing and what am I doing wrong?

On this page:

https://platinumdogs.me/2016/04/25/understanding-the-oauth2-redirect_uri-and-azure-ad-reply-url-parameters/

It says I should be able to add in a "Sign-On URL" and a "App ID URI" but I can't find those fields anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You should read a bit on the OAuth stuff, you can start [here](https://medium.com/@marilee.turscak/reply-urls-vs-postlogoutredirecturis-in-azure-active-directory-aad-20f57a03267b). As for the error it seems you need to configure reply URL for your Azure AD application.

go to Azure AD blade, open application, navigate to your application. Open settings and configure reply urls.

Comment: I've made some progress since this post, but I still can't resolve this problem. It is really strange and I can't figure out what's going on. I can get the app to work perfectly on my localhost with user authentication via Azure AD using Flask Dance. Then I upload the app to Azure, and it uploads successfully, but if I try going to the webapp, it times out. If I comment out all references to the Flask Dance, it uploads and runs perfectly. Something with Flask Dance has to be interfering with it running on Azure and I can't figure out what it could be.